# Adding part of a filename to a SQL Server column

Tags: sql, sql-server, filesystems

I am extracting data from a file daily and adding a timestamp to the `ActiveDate` column to capture when a particular record was imported.

Earlier we were using `getdate()` but we realized its not the most accurate solution for us. Fortunately the filename has a datestamp (something like XYZ 12232015).

Can I import the date as a date datatype into a field in Excel? I am not sure how to do that in SQL Server considering the file is saved on a shared drive. The file is moved to the archived folder after the SSIS package for the SQL code runs.

Comment: Could you better explain the desired flow? Can we define the file date in relation to the import day?

Answer (score 0):

In SSIS you can get this using a Derived File Transformation.

Comment: what kind of derived file transformation am I using? Could you please let me know what kind of variables are we using?